# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: null id generated for:class oneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

As the title,I got the following exception when I try to save Datas using Spring Data jpa.Please help me out to solve this problem because I still couldn't solve though searching familiar problems.

Class Activity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Activity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String activityName;
private String startTime;
private String endTime;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "activity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
private ActivityContent activityContent;


private Integer isDelete;

@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    isDelete = 0;
}
//setters and getters
}
```

Class ActivityContent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity_content")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class ActivityContent implements Serializable {

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "activity"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "activity_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long activityId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Activity activity;
//setters and getters
}
```

Dao Interface:

```
public interface ActivityDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Activity,Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<Activity>{
}
```

before invokes activityDao.save(activity),I have setted the below properties into activity and activityContent as the other blogs said ,but it's useless.

```
activityContent.setActivity(activity);
activity.setActivityContent(activityContent);
activityDao.save(activity);
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone help me out.

Exception Details:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: null id generated for:class com.gauldin.activity.orm.ActivityContent; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.gauldin.activity.orm.ActivityContent
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.save(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ActivityContent try using:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "activity_Id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Activity activity;
```

And when you assemble you should be saving thte ActivityContent as being the owner of OneToOne:

```
activityContent.setActivity(activity);
activityContentDao.save(activityContent);
```

If you want to be saving the Activity then you have to make it the owning side.

**Edit**

Also try to set the generator as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "activity_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long activityId;
```

Comment: I have try using Annotation @MapId And @JoinColumn(name = "activity_Id", referencedColumnName = "id"),but It didn't work out.
I have saved activityContent into activity to make activity owning the activityContent.
Just like this,activity.setActivityContent(activityContent);
right?

Comment: It still reported that exception org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: null id generated for:class com.gauldin.activity.orm.ActivityContent;

Comment: ok i forgot to add cascade = CascadeType.ALL.. check the updated post

Comment: Adding it on OneToOne like this?

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "activity_Id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Activity activity;

Still don't work...T.T

Comment: Are u saving like this? activityContent.setActivity(activity);
activityContentDao.save(activityContent);

Comment: yes,saving like  this:
activityContent.setActivity(activity);
activityContentDao.save(activityContent);
and here is my activityContent looks like in idea
activityContent = {ActivityContent@9460} 
 activityId = null
 content = "123"
 activity = {Activity@9467}

Comment: public interface ActivityContentDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ActivityContent, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<ActivityContent> {
}

Comment: try to change that generator is updated in the answer

Comment: afraid of different coding from your answer, I just copied ur answer to replace my codes.but ,still get the same exception;cryed.